# sIFR <object> hides the link in IE --> not clickable

Tags: internet-explorer, sifr, hyperlink

I tried lots of tricks but I can't manage to have them work !

In fact if I click just on the edges of the flash (in the margin of my replaced span), the links actually work.

And when my mouse goes over the sIFR replaced, the good url shows in the status bar...

It looks like the object is hiding the link...

Note : I cannot remove wmode-transparent nor float:left, and even when removing them, it doesn't work ...

Please help !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
onRelease: function(fi) {$(fi.getAncestor()).parent().click();return false;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using sIFR 2, make sure you're using 2.0.7. If sIFR 3, make sure you're using r436.